# Data mismatch between dataset and value in the leaflet map

Tags: r, leaflet, gis

I'm trying to create a choropleth map in county level using leaflet R package and I actually do it. But when I check my data file and the hover text of any county I find that the values are not correct. For example check the Conejos county. Any explanation? Or a better way to process tha data and create this map without the mismatches?

[image: Actual Dataset value]

[image: Leaflet Map Value]

Code:

```
library(raster)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

# Get USA polygon data
USA <- getData("GADM", country = "usa", level = 2)

### Get data
mydata <- read.csv("https://www.betydb.org/miscanthus_county_avg_yield.csv",
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  dplyr::select(COUNTY_NAME, Avg_yield)

### Check counties that exist in USA, but not in mydata
### Create a dummy data frame and bind it with mydata

mydata <- data.frame(COUNTY_NAME = setdiff(USA$NAME_2, mydata$COUNTY_NAME),
                     Avg_yield = NA,
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  bind_rows(mydata)

### Create a color palette
mypal <- colorNumeric(palette = "viridis", domain = mydata$Avg_yield)

leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
  setView(lat = 39.8283, lng = -98.5795, zoom = 4) %>%
  addPolygons(data = USA, stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 0.3,
              fillColor = ~mypal(mydata$Avg_yield),
              popup = paste("Region: ", USA$NAME_2, "<br>",
                            "Avg_yield: ", mydata$Avg_yield, "<br>")) %>%
  addLegend(position = "bottomleft", pal = mypal, values = mydata$Avg_yield,
            title = "Avg_yield",
            opacity = 1)
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, the data seems to come from Gilliam (Oregon), a county with the same value for the `CNTY_FIPS` field than Cojenos (Colorado). I wonder if `CNTY_FIPS` is being used internally as a (not really) unique ID somehow.

Comment: You can check the CNTY_FIPS by mydata <- read.csv("https://www.betydb.org/miscanthus_county_avg_yield.csv",
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)